# What are the basic rules for Nirahara Samyama?

Tags: scripture, practice, yoga, vedic-rituals, yoga-sutras

I read some where that Vedic science even gives us the choice of living without food. This can be achieved through a yogic process called **Nirahara Samyama** by which we learn to awaken our bio memory to produce energy from prana, water and sunlight, just like plants or trees.

What are the basic rules to be followed for this? Are there any scriptures that point out in this direction?